# gmail says user is over quota, though user has a lot of space

Tags: gmail, mailgun

I use mailgun to send messages to my clients.
Some of mails get failed with this error from gmail:

```
4.2.2 The email account that you tried to reach is over quota. Please direct\n4.2.2 the recipient to\n4.2.2  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=OverQuotaTemp
```

But whenever we check the user's storage space, it seems that it has a lot of space.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't know a lot about Gmail and mailgun, but you could be exceeding the number of emails you can send during a certain period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem was that one of the bcc's mailbox was full. I didn't expect that it will prevent from everybody getting the mail.
This is very odd behaviour.

Comment: The error message also says that maybe the mailbox is not full, but has been receiving too many messages recently. In this case, it's kind of a DDoS protection, as noone will be able to purposefully make somebody's else mailbox full in order to frustrate that person. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancel_culture .